# $\frac{a}{1+b^{2} c}+\frac{b}{1+c^{2} d}+\frac{c}{1+d^{2} a}+\frac{d}{1+a^{2} b} \geq 2 $

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

**Question** -

Suppose that $a, b, c, d$ are four positive real numbers with sum 4.
Prove that
$$
\frac{a}{1+b^{2} c}+\frac{b}{1+c^{2} d}+\frac{c}{1+d^{2} a}+\frac{d}{1+a^{2} b} \geq 2
$$

**my doubt** -

Solution.- According to AM-GM, we deduce that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{a}{1+b^{2} c} &=a-\frac{a b^{2} c}{1+b^{2} c} \geq a-\frac{a b^{2} c}{2 b \sqrt{c}}=a-\frac{a b \sqrt{c}}{2} \\
&=a-\frac{b \sqrt{a \cdot a c}}{2} \geq a-\frac{b(a+a c)}{4}
\end{aligned}
$$
According to this estimation,
$$
\sum_{c y c} \frac{a}{1+b^{2} c} \geq \sum_{c y c} a-\frac{1}{4} \sum_{c y c} a b-\frac{1}{4} \sum_{c y c} a b c
$$
By AM-GM inequality again, it's easy to refer that
$$
\sum_{c y c} a b \leq \frac{1}{4}\left(\sum_{c y c} a\right)^{2}=4 \quad ; \quad \sum_{c y c} a b c \leq \frac{1}{16}\left(\sum_{c y c} a\right)^{3}=4
$$

***now i did not understand how they got to this both results using am - gm*** 
$$
\sum_{c y c} a b \leq \frac{1}{4}\left(\sum_{c y c} a\right)^{2}=4 \quad ; \quad \sum_{c y c} a b c \leq \frac{1}{16}\left(\sum_{c y c} a\right)^{3}=4
$$

i think i am missing something easy...

any hints ??

thankyou

Comment: can anyone help plss....

Comment: It's just Cauchy, or rearrangement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_{cyc} ab = (a+c)(b+d) \leq \left(\frac{ (a+b+c+d)}{2} \right)^2$

This happens to work for 4 variables, but not other cases.

---

In Pham's book, example 1.1.4 is:

$16 (abc+bcd+cda+dab) = 16ab(c+d)+16cd(a+b) $
$\leq 4(a+b)^2(c+d) + 4(c+d)^2 (a+b)$
$= 4 (a+b+c+d)(a+b)(c+d)$
$\leq (a+b+c+d)^3$.

Comment: The other one is just [Muirhead's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality), or more directly, [Maclaurin's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality).

Comment: @Batominovski using am-gm ? .

Comment: @User88463 Sure, expand $(a+b+c+d)^3$ into $\sum\limits_{\text{sym}}\,a^3+3\,\sum\limits_{\text{sym}}\,a^2b+6\,\sum\limits_{\text{sym}}\,abc$.  Prove by AM-GM that $$\sum\limits_{\text{sym}}\,a^3\geq \sum_{\text{sym}}\,abc=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\,abc$$ and $$\sum_{\text{sym}}\,a^2b\geq 3\, \sum_{\text{sym}}\,abc=3\,\sum_{\text{cyc}}\,abc\,.$$  In fact, Maclaurin's Inequality can be inductively proven from just AM-GM with $2$ variables (but you will also need [Rolle's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem)).

Comment: thanks but is there a way without expanding rhs..?? like 1st one proven by calvin...

Comment: @User88463  So, you don't want to work at all to get a proof of that inequality?  It's not like the expansion is unmanageable.

Comment: To back up Batominovski, a lot of "solution only via AM-GM" is via "bunching together humongous amounts of terms" (which, in essence, is what Muirhead is)

Comment: @Batominovski no,its not that i do not want to work at all...because author writes that we infer easily by am-gm thats why i think there should be some easier proof ...but i will work on your hint,thanks

Comment: @User88463  I consider the proof I just gave easy.  It is a standard trick, and that is probably why the author said "easily."  I don't know any easier proof.

Comment: @User88463 See example 1.1.4.  (On a separate note, Pham's book is quite advanced, and I would not recommend it as a first text into inequalities. Read it after you've mastered the basics.)

Comment: ohhh,yes i forget it that they have proved the result before...thankyou so much calvin ...and i value your suggestions but i have studied inequalities in detail quite a long time ago thats why i forget some easy tricks and asking silly doubts but now i am on my track ...